# Separator line UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have this table view but the separator line looks like double line

[image]

In the storyboard I have this settings (table view):

- Style: Plain
- Separator: None

This is my code:

```
class ListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var transactionList: ransactionList!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        let separator = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: bounds.size.height - 0.5, width: bounds.size.width - 22, height: 1))
        separator.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        contentView.addSubview(separator)
    }

}
```

I expected something like this:
[image]

Comment: What do mean by double line here?

Comment: Try to add separator line in xib of cell and remove code of add programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I made my own seperator line in the UITableViewDataSourceDelegate method.

```
//Separator Full Line
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        cell.separatorInset = .zero
        cell.layoutMargins = .zero
```

I believe I also had

```
separatorStyle="default"
```

on the tableview